# How to add security policies for web-logic console(Not oracle SOA suite)

Tags: java, security, weblogic, jax-ws, jdeveloper

We have generated web-service client with policies("oracle/wss_username_token_client_policy") which is based on end point had been implemented ..

The code we developed is working in jdeveloper with oracle SOA suite.. since it is having OWSM features in built. the same application we have to deploy in the web-logic console which doesn't support any OWSM features..

Question 1: How do we implement code level to make it work in web-logic console..I mean with out support of OWSM features. suppose we have way to use OWSM which API(jar files) we need to take..

Answer (score 0):

You can add/remove policies in many ways:

1) Via the Administration Console at runtime.

2) Via Fusion Middleware Control

3) In J-developer

If you want to remove the policies then in J-developer open project >> Web Content >> WEB-INF >> Policies

remove the xml file like UserNameToken.xml